Cannot access file being used for another application for read
I need to access a file for read, but I have the error "the file is being used by another program". Is there a way to open it while it's being used?. I've tried several options but cannot resolve it.
I use frequently other software that can access this file in the same situation, so It must be a way to do it possible.
Here is my code:
    Private Sub TimTemporizador1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TimTemporizador1.Tick

    If TebIntervaloComprobacion.Text = "" Then TebIntervaloComprobacion.Text = "5"

    TimTemporizador1.Interval = (Convert.ToInt32(TebIntervaloComprobacion.Text)) * 1000

    Dim ResultadoBusqueda As String = BuscarEnArchivo(TebArchivo.Text, TebTextoABuscar.Text)

End Sub


Public Function BuscarEnArchivo(ByVal RutaBusqueda As String, ByVal CadenaBusqueda As String) As String

    Dim Archivo As New System.IO.StreamReader(RutaBusqueda)
    Dim LineaTextoActual As String = String.Empty
    Dim ResultadoBusqueda As String = String.Empty
    Dim NumeroLineaActual As Integer = 1

    Try

        Do While Archivo.EndOfStream = False

            LineaTextoActual = Archivo.ReadLine

            If NumeroLineaActual > UltimoNumeroLineaBusquedaAnterior Then

                If LineaTextoActual.IndexOf(CadenaBusqueda) > -1 Then

                    ResultadoBusqueda = LineaTextoActual
                    UltimoNumeroLineaBusquedaAnterior = NumeroLineaActual

                    TebTextoEncontrado.Text = ResultadoBusqueda
                    TebLineaEncontrado.Text = UltimoNumeroLineaBusquedaAnterior.ToString
                    TebFecha.Text = Now.ToShortDateString
                    TebHora.Text = New TimeSpan(TimeOfDay.Hour, TimeOfDay.Minute, TimeOfDay.Second).ToString

                    If ChbEnviarCorreo.Checked Then

                        CorreoAsunto = TebFecha.Text & " " & TebHora.Text & " - Excepción encontrada."
                        CorreoMensaje = "Excepción encontrada en la línea " & NumeroLineaActual.ToString & ":" & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine &
                            TebFecha.Text & " " & TebHora.Text & Environment.NewLine &
                            ResultadoBusqueda

                        EnviaCorreo()

                    End If

                    Exit Do

                End If

            End If

            NumeroLineaActual += 1

        Loop

        Return ResultadoBusqueda

    Catch ex As Exception

        Return String.Empty

    End Try

End Function


The following may be of interest: FileStream.

Thanks user246821, but I'm not able to make it work I´ve tried some examples but get the same problem "file is using by another program". It has a lot of constructors, so I'm lost. Could you give me a piece of code that make it success?

The following may be of interest: Process Monitor

Useful software user246821, but I know which process has opened the file I try to read. What I need is read it at the same time, because the other process shouldn't by stopped. It's the process which generates the file.
